# Mongodb: project to return the field in array of object without using unwind

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need get value of field without using $unwind 
because $unwind and $group takes much longer time.

My document (looks like):

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
"providers" : [ 
    {
        "list" : [ 
            {
                "code" : "ATT",
                "descr" : "Attending"
            }
        ],
        "Name" : "John Doe",
        "prvdId" : "1"
    }, 
    {
        "list" : [ 
            {
                "code" : "RFR",
                "descr" : "Referring"
            }, 
            {
                "code" : "TRT",
                "descr" : "Treating"
            }
        ],
        "Name" : "Smith William",
        "prvdId" : "2"
    }
]
```

}

cond is if  "code" : "TRT", than get "prvdId"

Expected result is

```
{"prvdId" : "2"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$filter` with $in to look for a match in nested array followed by `$let` with `$arrayElemAt` to output prvdId in 3.4.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"providers.list.code":"TRT"}},
  {"$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "prvdId":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{
          "providersl":{
            "$filter":{
              "input":"$providers",
              "as":"providerf",
              "cond":{"$in":["TRT","$$providerf.list.code"]}
            }
          }
        },
        "in":{"$arrayElemAt":["$$providersl.prvdId",0]}
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks Veeram, but can you please clarify why use of $let. and if there is no value match in array should return null.

Comment: Yw. $filters returns an array. So in your case array with single element when match is found else empty array. We convert the array into document using  `$let` to create a temporary variable (`providersl`) followed by `$arrayElemAt` with 0 index to output the first value or else its just null. Let me know if that answer your question.

Comment: Yes, i got what needed and it changed my approach to match fields. Thanks for explaining. it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description as a solution expected result can be obtained by using $elemMatch operator  used to search an array element into find operation.

```
db.collection.find({
    providers: {
        $elemMatch: {
            list: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    code: "TRT"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    'providers.$.prvdId': 1
})
```